# How to group by values in a column and find time difference using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe as shown below:

| Col A | Time | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2018-01-06 03:45:23 | B | 1 |
| 141 | 2018-01-08 12:45:55 | C | 0 |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 11:45:29 | A | 0 |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 01:45:15 | C | 0 |
| 141 | 2018-01-08 11:35:06 | C | 0 |
| 123 | 2018-01-09 10:45:37 | A | 1 |
| 123 | 2018-01-09 09:45:41 | C | 0 |
| 141 | 2018-01-06 03:45:28 | B | 0 |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 12:45:23 | C | 0 |
| 141 | 2018-01-08 11:45:17 | A | 0 |
| 141 | 2018-01-08 01:45:02 | C | 0 |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 11:35:56 | C | 0 |
| 141 | 2018-01-09 10:45:39 | A | 0 |
| 141 | 2018-01-09 09:45:19 | C | 0 |
| 178 | 2019-04-17 08:34:13 | B | 1 |
| 178 | 2019-05-02 19:48:44 | C | 0 |
| 178 | 2019-04-18 13:27:28 | A | 1 |

For this dataframe, there are two operations that need to be performed:

1. *I have to group by values in `Col A` sort it by `Time` and calculate the lagging time difference*
2. *Filter the dataframe only for values `B` and `A` in `Col B`, and apply the above operation*
3. *Keeping the conditions in Step 2, Calculate time difference for each `A` in `Col B` from the very first timestamp value of that group by value in `Col A`*
4. *Keeping the filter conditions in Step 2, and where the value of `Col C` is `1`, calculate time difference of `B` and `A` of `Col B`. In this case, only one `B` and one `A` for each group of `Col A` can have value `1` in `Col C`*

For both the above steps, a new column should be created. In case 2, where the value in column `Col B` is `C`, in the newly created column it should be filled with NaN. Can someone please help with this implementation using Python?

**Expected Output:**

| Col A | Time | Col B | Col C | Lag Time | Filtered Lag | Diff | New Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2018-01-06 03:45:23 | B | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 01:45:15 | C | 0 | 165592 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 11:35:56 | C | 0 | 35441 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 11:45:29 | A | 0 | 573 | 201606 | 201606 | NaN |
| 123 | 2018-01-08 12:45:23 | C | 0 | 3594 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 123 | 2018-01-09 09:45:41 | C | 0 | 75618 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 123 | 2018-01-09 10:45:37 | A | 1 | 3596 | 82808 | 284414 | 284414 |
| 178 | 2019-04-17 08:34:13 | B | 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 178 | 2019-04-18 13:27:28 | A | 1 | 103995 | 103995 | 103995 | 103995 |
| 178 | 2019-05-02 19:48:44 | C | 0 | 1232476 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Similarly for other values in `Col A` also it should calculate values for new columns.

**Note:** Values in new columns are calculated in seconds

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: `df.groupby('Col A')['Time'].diff()` and `df.groupby(['Col A', 'Col B'])['Time'].diff()`?

Comment: @mozway- I have added the sample output

Comment: The input is much longer than the output. Where did the rest of the DataFrame go?

Comment: For 141, I truncated the dataframe, calculating these values manually was time taking- @enke

Answer (score 1):

Would this work? The first column seems straightforward. For the second column, we use `where` to only work with rows with `A` or `B` in `ColB`.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['new'] = df.sort_values('Time').groupby('Col A')['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
df['new2'] = df['Time'].where(df['Col B'].isin(['A','B'])).groupby(df['Col A']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff()).droplevel(0).dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
    Col A                Time Col B        new      new2
0     123 2018-01-06 03:45:23     B        NaN       NaN
1     141 2018-01-08 12:45:55     C     3638.0       NaN
2     123 2018-01-08 11:45:29     A      573.0  201606.0
3     123 2018-01-08 01:45:15     C   165592.0       NaN
4     141 2018-01-08 11:35:06     C    35404.0       NaN
5     123 2018-01-09 10:45:37     A     3596.0   82808.0
6     123 2018-01-09 09:45:41     C    75618.0       NaN
7     141 2018-01-06 03:45:28     B        NaN       NaN
8     123 2018-01-08 12:45:23     C     3594.0       NaN
9     141 2018-01-08 11:45:17     A      611.0  201589.0
10    141 2018-01-08 01:45:02     C   165574.0       NaN
11    123 2018-01-08 11:35:56     C    35441.0       NaN
12    141 2018-01-09 10:45:39     A     3620.0   82822.0
13    141 2018-01-09 09:45:19     C    75564.0       NaN
14    178 2019-04-17 08:34:13     B        NaN       NaN
15    178 2019-05-02 19:48:44     C  1232476.0       NaN
16    178 2019-04-18 13:27:28     A   103995.0  103995.0
```

Comment: In this is it possible to add a new column based on `new2` column condition, and calculate the difference for each of `A` in `Col B` by the first time value for each group by of `Col A`?

Comment: Added a new column in the expected output dataframe, please check it once @enke

Comment: @ShadabHussain maybe it's better to start a new question for the new columns. You've modified your question to cram in a lot of questions some of which won't necessarily be useful to others searching for a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution to the above question meeting all the conditions:

```
# Converting `Time` column to `datetime`
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

# Group by `Col A` after sorting by `Time` and calculate row difference in seconds for each group
df['Lag Time'] = df.sort_values('Time').groupby('Col A')['Time'].diff().dt.total_seconds()

# Filter dataframe where value of `Col B` is in `["A", "B"]`, group by `Col A` then sort by `Time` using lambda function and calculate row difference in seconds for each group
df['Filtered Lag'] = df['Time'].where(df['Col B'].isin(['B','A'])).groupby(df['Col A']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff()).droplevel(0).dt.total_seconds()

# Filter dataframe where value of `Col B` is in `["A", "B"]` and value of `Col C` is `1`, group by `Col A` then sort by `Time` using lambda function and calculate row difference in seconds for each group
df['Diff'] = df['Time'].where(df['Col B'].isin(['B','A']) & df['Col C']==1).groupby(df['Col A']).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().diff()).droplevel(0).dt.total_seconds()
```

Values for `New Col` are yet to be calculated, will post the updated answer soon.